# CSS cascading term

Tags: css

The cascading term in CSS is related to the fact
that having more style sources combine them together
or only to the fact to the conflict order resolution?

Thanks

Comment: The CSS cascade is quite an elaborate process that can't be explained in just one sentence methinks...

Comment: That's your opinion and I'm not agree. So I don't want close this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the cascade defines the order conflicting styles will resolve.

Comment: But however if I have for example in a style element div {color:red;} and then a div with a style attribute with background-color:yellow this div will have both because they are combined together in cascading...

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However if the second style was div {color:blue}, this would override the earlier style; that is the cascade/specificity.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of help. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade.

It seems that you have the right assumption.